# Android Video from camera

Tags: android, android-camera, augmented-reality, android-camera-intent

What should I read for creating a basic augmented reality app for android?
I read the android reference articles, and I learnd that I could use the Intent(using the built in app) or construct my own "costumized" app (with camera).
I wanted to know what I should read more about, so that I could create something basic like a shape on the screen

By the way:
Cant I just see the current image given by the camera with out the need of saving it? (all of the articles want me to save the files captured, and as you know augmented reality(in my case) does not need saving the file, but does it "on the fly" , am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see the preview using surfaceview while recording from a mediarecorder.
the preview can be seen using setPreviewDisplayfunction of media recorder. its pretty simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you have a look at OpenCV. I have not used it with Android, but I know it to be a fairly painless and accessible way to image processing.